# Sending signal to bash shell launched in GVim

Tags: bash, vim, signals

How do I send a signal (say, SIGINT), to a shell launched inside GVim, using a keyboard shortcut?

Neither Ctrl+C nor Ctrl+D seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+D seems to work for me, at least for closing a terminal session. Crl+C however does not. If you only want to kill a running process, you can do this workaround (provided Ctrl+Z) works for you.

Press Ctrl+Z to pause the process, then

```
kill %1
```

to kill the process in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Inside vim, use command `:sh`to temporarily exit vim and go to shell
If you want to go back to vim then press `Ctrl + D`. This work for me for years.